# One-to-Many Spatial Join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join, relates

I am trying to join attributes from 2 shapefiles. 1 shapefile is a polygon layer indicating police precincts and the second is a point layer with crime statistics for each police station. The police station and the police precinct are the same.
The police station layer that contains the crime statistics has roughly 40 points per police station. See attached police station image

[image].

I want to join this layers table to the police precinct layer (See attached precinct layer image)

[image]

The trouble I am having with this, is that when i use the Join by location tool, it only takes the first 17 records from the police stations layer and appends the data to the existing 17 police precincts.
I need it to append all 40 crimes points to the precincts layer without creating 40 polygons that lie ontop of oneanother. Just 1 polygon with multiple crime records.
Does anyone know how to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, you don't need a spatial join. Use Project > Project Properties > Relations. Use 'Precincts' as the parent and 'Stations' as the child. Use "Station" and "COMPNT_NM" as the join fields.

Edit:
If you then use the identify features tool and click on a precinct, you will get a form pop up with all the attributes for the precinct plus a list of all the associated crimes. See the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#forms-for-1-n-relations) for further details

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion. The reason that I never considered a relate is that I would like to/need to be able to display the information contained in the "Police Stations" layer spatially rather than just viewing it in table format,  So as to be able to visually compare "police precinct" and the crime in each of them. I hope this maybe provides some further clarification regarding this.  Unless I am completely missing the point of a join/relate here.

Comment: Is this just for visual representation then? You can style all the crimes according to the precinct they are associated with. If I've still got this wrong, can you provide an example of what you want to do with the data... Eg run some sort of query or spatial statistics?

Comment: So the idea with this data is two-fold. Firstly just to have a visual representation of the data and secondly the end goal is to take the crime statistics and to analyze them in conjunction with population demographics  to produce some meaningful statistics for each police precinct or any other administrative polygons. To achieve this, the approach will be by assigning the statistics to a common feature e.g. Electrical connection points to the main grid, each building has this, and then doing the same with census data. This would then be the basis of that analysis and density comparisons

Comment: I think a relation is the way to go. I've edited my answer to include some details on what to do with it once you've set the relation up

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be a `Virtual Layer`.

From the menu, go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer` and [Import] your layers.

Assuming polygon layer name is `precinct` and point layer is `station`, following query will create a new `virtual layer` (polygon) :

```
SELECT precinct.*, 
       station.Station,
       station.Type,
       station.Crime_ca_1,
       station.2005-2006
FROM precinct CROSS JOIN station 
ON st_intersects(precinct.geometry, station.geometry) = 1
```

In the above example I had stopped at the field `2005-2006` (as `station.2005-2006`) but please add all required fields following `comma(, )`.

After checking the result please save this layer as new Shapefile.